# Factorial for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, factorial

I created the following funcion to calculate the factorial of a given number:

```
factorial <- function(x){
y <- 1
for(i in 1:x){
y <-y*((1:x)[i])
print(y)
}

}


factorial(6)

in console:

[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 6
[1] 24
[1] 120
[1] 720
```

6!=720 so obviously the last number is correct and the calculation does work for all numbers.

The problem is I only want the last number to be printed to console, is there any way to do that? I´ve been trying to turn y into a vector within the function but it doesn`t seem to work.

Comment: Why are you not just doing `factorial(1:6)`?

Comment: Or just `factorial(6)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the print statement outside the loop?

```
for(i in 1:x){
    y <-y*((1:x)[i])
}
print(y)
```

Comment: Happens to the best of us. :)

Comment: Note though that this is a horrible way to calculate the factorial when using R.

Comment: That it is. Standard library functions are always better.

Comment: You do realize that the `print(y)` is not necessary if you are just calling `factorial(6)`, as this will automagically print the result.

Answer (score 3):

`print` prints to the screen. A function will return the result of last evaluated expression (or an explicit `return` value). Do you want to return the value as well as print it?

That being said

`R` already has a  function `factorial` which calls `gamma(x+1)`, using the fact that for integer values [`gamma(x+1) == x!`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

so

```
factorial(6)

gamma(7)
```

The function you wrote will have integer overflow issues when  multiplying  large numbers, as well as being highly inefficient as you are repeatedly reassigning to `y` within a loop (recursive when it doesn't need to be)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `print()` outside the loop

```
factorial <- function(x){
y <- 1
for(i in 1:x){
y <-y*((1:x)[i])
}
print(y)
}
```

You can improve this function... why `(1:x)[i]` and not only `i`? Why `print()` and not `return()`? And the most important: why don't use `factorial()` from base package?

Answer (score 0):

```
# take input from the user
n <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a number: "))
factorial = 1 #set factorial variable to 1

# check is the number is negative, positive or zero
if(n < 0) {
  print("factorial does not exist for negative numbers")
} else if(n == 0) {
  print("The factorial of 0 is 1")
} else {
  for(i in 1:n) #for loop to expand n up to 1
    {
    factorial = factorial * i 
  }
  print(paste("The factorial of", n ,"is",factorial))
}
```

Comment: this seems a much easier way ,if you can embed it into a function it works perfectly

Comment: are the question and answer written in the same language ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your factorial function by using return function at the end of your code:

```
factorial<-function(x){
        y<-1
        for(i in 1:x) {
        y<-y*((1:x)[i])
                      }
        return(y) 
            }
```